# jQuery: execute a code snippet onload AND in a bound function

Tags: jquery

Here's part of my code for a jQuery word counter.  My question is: how do I execute the part that counts the words and displays the result when the page -loads- as well as on keyup, click, blur etc. events?   I could copy-and-paste, but that seems so sloppy.  Or I could pull the repeated bit into another function, but then my $(this) variable won't work anymore.  What to do?

```
$(".count").each(function() {

  // Set up max words
  maxWords = 200;

  // Set up div to display word count after my textarea
  $(this).after('<div class="word-count"><strong>0</strong> Words ('+maxWords+' Maximum)</div>');

  // Bind function to count the words
  $(this).bind('keyup click blur focus change paste', function() {

    // Count the words
    var numWords = jQuery.trim($(this).val()).replace(/\s+/g," ").split(' ').length;

    // Display the result
    $(this).next('.word-count').children('strong').text(numWords);
  });
});
```

Comment: just wrap it in `$(function() {///your call });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On this part, just trigger it once after binding, like this:

```
$(this).bind('keyup click blur focus change paste', function() {
  var numWords = jQuery.trim($(this).val()).replace(/\s+/g," ").split(' ').length;
  $(this).next('.word-count').children('strong').text(numWords);
}).keyup();
```

This triggers the `keyup` event one time, the one you just bound, so when this code runs, it'll trigger the handler you just bound to run immediately once as well.